# Firebase messaging sendToDevice() new API?

Tags: node.js, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

The "old / version 8" JavaScript API for Firebase messaging had a function for sending a notification to the mobile device:

```
admin.messaging().sendToDevice(...)
```

The "new / modular / version 9" JavaScript API fetches the messaging object with `getMessaging(app)`, but this object does not seem to have any function, either actual or documented, to do the equivalent. I cannot find a similar function anywhere in the new API--not even in "messaging-compat", which is supposed to simulate the old API in the new one. Is it just not there?  Will I have to forgo the new API entirely just to get this one function?  Or perhaps is this functionality moved to some other API?

I'm trying to do this from within a Firebase Cloud Function, if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, you can just pass the token in the `to` property of the JSON object you pass to `send` like shown in this code from the documentation on [sending messages to specific devices](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-specific-devices):

```
// This registration token comes from the client FCM SDKs.
const registrationToken = 'YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN';

const message = {
  data: {
    score: '850',
    time: '2:45'
  },
  token: registrationToken
};

// Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
// registration token.
getMessaging().send(message)
```

Comment: You are describing the old "firebase-admin" SDK. Is that not the "old / non-modular / version 8" way of doing things, or is that still an active SDK alongside the newer one ( https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/messaging_?authuser=0 )?

Comment: `getMessaging` is v9, it would've been `admin.messaging()` before. So I'm pretty sure that documentation was updated for v9. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: The object returned by getMessaging() does not have a send() or similar method, either in the documentation or anywhere in the source code.

Comment: Hmm... interesting. I'm not sure what's happening in that case, as I must admit I also had a hard time parsing the reference documentation (which is generated from the source code so more or less guaranteed to be up to date with that code).

Comment: NodeJS seems to be the red-headed stepchild of cloud APIs. Google is actively working on and improving the Go APIs and actively neglecting JavaScript/Typescript. This is just one of many such instances I have found: I opened an issue on googleapis/nodejs-iot that hasn't been looked at for months. I'll open an issue here. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `getMessaging()` returns a `Messaging` object which contains all the usual methods including `sendToDevice()`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.messaging.messaging.md#messaging_class. What makes you think this class doesn't have any methods?